# Binding the Trigger value dynamic in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, triggers, styles

I'm using `ListView` along with the `GridView` for displaying the data in tabular format:

```
<ListView>
 <ListView.View>
   <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
     <GridViewColumn Header="Risk" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RiskName}" />
   </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I have to change the background color based on the `RiskName`. For example, if `RiskName` is "High" then the background would be Red, if `RiskName` is "Medium" then the background would be "Yellow", and so on.

I added the style along with trigger to set background based on the value,

```
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="High">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="Medium">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</Trigger>
```

It works fine, but in my case the text of the `RiskName` is not constant. The value comes dynamically. In WPF is there any way I can set the Value of trigger property dynamically which look something like this?

```
<Trigger Property="Text" Value="{Binding RiskName}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RiskBrush}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Any suggestion? If not then what is the other work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<converters:MyBrushLookupConverter x:Key="brushLookup" BrushDictionary="{Binding KeyedBrushes}" />
```

where MyBrushLookupConverter looks like

```
public class MyBrushLookupConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
   // This is a dependency property - dependency property gumf omitted for brevity
   public Dictionary<string, Brush> BrushDictionary {get; set;}

   // Convert method
   public Convert(object value, ...)
   {
      return BrushDictionary[(string)value];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Converter` instead of a `Trigger`. Bind the `Background` to `RiskName` and write a converter that returns a `Brush` determined by the value of `RiskName`.

Link to MSDN for the interface you need to use `IValueConverter` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

A link to a good tutorial on Converters: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but using the converter approach,I need to also hard coded values in c# code like if RiskName is high than return Red brush and so on which same like hard coded Trigger above.

Comment: Is there a list of colours that map to `RiskName` stored somewhere in your model then? i.e. what provides the mapping of `RiskName` to a colour?