# How can i change datagrid row's foreground based on a condition?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hy, I am new in WPF programming and I have a little problem that I can't solve it by my self.

I have created a list of object:

```
    List<TestInfo> Info = new List<TestInfo>();
```

where TestInfo:

```
    public class TestInfo
    {
        public string Serial { get; set; }
        public string Test { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
```

After that I have grouped it:

```
        ListCollectionView groupedInfo = new ListCollectionView(Info);
        groupedInfo.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Serial"));
```

Then binded it to datagrid:

```
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = groupedInfo;
```

Now, my question is, in this case, how can i change datagrid's row forecolor based on a condition? Something like: if groupedInfo.Result == F change row forecolor.
I can't manage to do it myself. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it based on a condition:

```
 <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style x:Key="DGCell" TargetType="{x:Type DGCell}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

And to use it on a column you do:

```
 <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DGCell">
```

Comment: I have yet to see a way to change for an entire row, but changing for all columns would give that illusion. Which is what this would do:  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style x:Key="DGCell" TargetType="{x:Type DGCell}" >

Comment: I am not really sure how to use your code.. I've pasted it into <DataGrid> </Datagrid> section and I get one error: Key attribute can be used only on a tag contained in an IDictionary type property. I suppose i have to make a connection between your code and my condition in code behind(c#).

Comment: Here is a link describing how to bind to a dynamic trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444178/binding-the-trigger-value-dynamic-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. I have finally solved it and learned what triggers are [:D]. The solution for me was using a DataTrigger. The code is below:

```
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Result}" Value="P">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```